# How to display "stop" message on screen when car reaches at a traffic signal?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have used box colliders and GUI function... but the problem with box collider is that your car stops after hitting the collider and and I also want message which is displayed on the sceen to be fade away after 10 seconds.

Here's my code:

```
var msg = false;
function OnCollisionEnter(theCollision : Collision)
{
  if(theCollision.gameObject.name == "trafficLight")
  {
    Debug.Log("collided");
    msg=true;

  }
}

function OnGUI () 
{
  if (msg== true) 
  {
    GUI.Box (Rect (100,0,500,50), "You need to stop if the traffic signal is red");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the problem with box collider is that your car stops after
>   hitting the collider

You should clarify this. Eventually post another question with the specific problem and possibly an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

> I also want message which is displayed on the sceen to be fade away
>   after 10 seconds.

Then put something like this inside the `Update` method of your `MonoBehavior`:

```
float timeElapsed;
float timeLimit = 10f;

void Update()
{
  if (msg)
  {
    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timeElapsed >= timeLimit)
    {
      msg = false;
      timeElapsed = 0f;
    }
  }
}
```

Alternative, for a more elegant approach, you can use coroutines:

```
IEnumerator FadeAfterTime(float timeLimit)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeLimit);
    msg = false;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
  if(theCollision.gameObject.name == "trafficLight")
  {

    msg=true;
    StartCoroutine(FadeAfterTime(10f)); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want a stop message to appear on the screen when the player is near a stop sign, so that the player has to stop the car himself.

In order to do this, for starters you'll need to make your box a trigger instead of a collider. There's a small tickbox on the collider of each object which says Trigger. You'll want this to be ticked.

Then put a script similar to this in the trigger box near your traffic light:

```
var msg = false;
function Start()
{
}

function OnTriggerEnter(theCollision : Collision)
{
  if(theCollision.gameObject.name == "car") //where "car" you put the name of the car object
  {
        msg = true;
        StartCoroutine(FadeAfterTime(10f));
  }
}

IEnumerator FadeAfterTime(float timeLimit)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeLimit);
    msg = false;
}

function OnGUI () 
{
    if (msg== true) 
    {
        GUI.Box (Rect (100,0,500,50), "You need to stop if the traffic signal is red");
    }

}

function Update()
{
}
```

In essence the traffic light trigger box will detect when the car enters the designated area, and will display the GUI, with the fade out script provided by Heisenbug in the previous answer.

I can't test this myself at the moment, but it should work for you. If you have any questions, lemme know.

Answer (score -1):

You should use RayCasting function for this purpose.
 I have provided a real example here.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class carMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    bool isStop = false;
    public float speed = 30f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!isStop) {
            transform.position += (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);

            var fwd = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward);
            Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, fwd, Color.green);
            if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, fwd, 10)) {
                print ("There is something in front of the object!");
                isStop = true;
                transform.position = transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make use of comments for suggestions and critique contents once you earns enough reputations.